# Count characters in a URL

Tags: jquery, url, count, character

Is there a way to count number of characters in a url using jquery? e.g

```
<a href="youtube.com">TEXT</a>
```

**youtube.com** contains 11 characters,

I know this wont work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = $('a').text().length;
    alert(count); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You need to read `href` attribute value and not the text

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = $('a').attr('href').length;
    alert(count); 
});
```

Comment: Note that `prop('href')` and `attr('href')` can give different values

Comment: Yes, `prop('href')` returns 85